# How can I set Database connection timeout using SQLAlchemy

Tags: database, postgresql, dbconnection

I want to set connection timeout for DB connection.
I have used this code

```
conn_string = "postgresql://username:password:2345/devstr100"
engine = create_engine(
        conn_string,
        connect_args={"connect_timeout":10},
        pool_pre_ping=True
    )
```

and also tried with timeout instead of connect_timeout in the code block, but getting this error.

Due to load on the PostgreSQL Database or downtime, the lambda function gives timeout and triggers repeatedly, but the request is loaded on DB for infinite time.

Database access timed out: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 2345 failed: FATAL:  unrecognised configuration parameter "connect_timeout"

Even in the documentation it said to use connect_timeout

PostgreSQL version : 10
SQLAlchemy version : 1.4.46

Comment: 1) Is the Postgres server really listening on port 2345? 2) What happens if you don't use the `connect_args`? 3) Also need to provide more information a) Postgres version b) SQLAlchemy version.  c) The value for `conn_string`. **Add information as text update to question**.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver added the following details, pls look into it

Comment: This '...the lambda function gives timeout...' would indicate you are not using the community Postgres but something else, I'm guessing AWS related. Is that the case? If so provide more information about what you are actually using.

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL community version only, but the lambda function is AWS related, which tries to run and query on Postgresql DB, so if DB is down , or overloaded the Lambda connecting to DB should give a timeout

Comment: Where is the Postgres database located and where did you get it from? *connection to server at "localhost"* would imply it is the same location as the lambda function.

Comment: I connected postgreSQL on localhost, to test this code block locally, whether connection is interrupted or not after timeout timing is passed, as u can see their is no lambda involvement in this code block, I am connecting with the DB and running code on ipython, to check it locally, that lambda thing is to tell what and why I want to add timeout.

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying.To your question add a step by step description of what you are doing for a given procedure, either the lambda one or the localhost one.